# Finding overlapping regions in large DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame in pandas with genomic regions represented by their chromosome, start position, and stop position. I'm trying to identify overlapping regions within the same chromosome and compile them along with their corresponding labels. I'm not sure if the way that I'm doing is correct-- also I want an efficient approach since my df is very large (3 million rows), so a for loop is not ideal.

I have access to 8 cores- I assumed my code was using them (not sure), but should I add something to parallelize my code to make it faster?

Here's my current approach:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'chromosome': ['chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1'],
    'start': [10, 15, 35, 45, 55],
    'stop': [20, 25, 55, 56, 60],
    'hg_38_locs': ['chr1:10-20', 'chr1:15-25', 'chr1:35-55', 'chr1:45-56', 'chr1:55-60'],
    'main_category': ['label1', 'label2', 'label2', 'label3', 'label1']
}
full_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Initialize lists to store overlapping regions and their labels
overlapping_regions = []
overlapping_labels = []

# Iterate through each row and check for overlaps
for i in range(len(full_df)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(full_df)):
        # Check if chromosomes match
        if full_df['chromosome'][i] != full_df['chromosome'][j]:
            continue
        
        # Check for overlap using start and stop positions
        if full_df['stop'][i] >= full_df['start'][j] and full_df['start'][i] <= full_df['stop'][j]:
            overlapping_regions.append((full_df['hg_38_locs'][i], full_df['hg_38_locs'][j]))
            overlapping_labels.append((full_df['main_category'][i], full_df['main_category'][j]))

# Create a new DataFrame to compile the information
compiled_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'overlapping_regions': overlapping_regions,
    'overlapping_labels': overlapping_labels
})

# Display the compiled DataFrame
print(compiled_df)
```

Output:

```
  overlapping_regions overlapping_labels
0    (chr1:10-20, chr1:15-25)        (label1, label2)
1    (chr1:10-20, chr1:35-55)        (label1, label2)
2    (chr1:15-25, chr1:35-55)        (label2, label2)
3    (chr1:35-55, chr1:45-56)        (label2, label3)
4    (chr1:45-56, chr1:55-60)        (label3, label1)
```

Comment: Kindly share the expected output dataframe.

Comment: How heavily duplicated is the `chromosome` column

Comment: 3 million rows divided sort of evenly across 25 chromosomes. So around 120K each. I just added the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `joblib` library for parallel processing.

```
import pandas as pd
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

# Sample DataFrame

data = {
    'chromosome': ['chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1'],
    'start': [10, 15, 35, 45, 55],
    'stop': [20, 25, 55, 56, 60],
    'hg_38_locs': ['chr1:10-20', 'chr1:15-25', 'chr1:35-55', 'chr1:45-56', 'chr1:55-60'],
    'main_category': ['label1', 'label2', 'label2', 'label3', 'label1']
}

full_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function to check for overlapping regions
def check_overlap(i, full_df):
    overlapping_regions = []
    overlapping_labels = []
    for j in range(i + 1, len(full_df)):
        if full_df['chromosome'][i] != full_df['chromosome'][j]:
            continue
        if full_df['stop'][i] >= full_df['start'][j] and full_df['start'][i] <= full_df['stop'][j]:
    

overlapping_regions.append((full_df['hg_38_locs'][i], full_df['hg_38_locs'][j]))
    

overlapping_labels.append((full_df['main_category'][i], full_df['main_category'][j]))
return overlapping_regions, overlapping_labels

# Parallelize the process
results = Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(check_overlap)(i, full_df) for i in range(len(full_df)))

# Extract overlapping regions and labels
overlapping_regions = [result[0] for result in results if result[0]]
overlapping_labels = [result[1] for result in results if result[1]]

# Flatten the lists
overlapping_regions = [item for sublist in overlapping_regions for item in sublist]
overlapping_labels = [item for sublist in overlapping_labels for item in sublist]

# Create DataFrame
compiled_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'overlapping_regions': overlapping_regions,
    'overlapping_labels': overlapping_labels
})

print(compiled_df)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Does that make it faster though? I tried time.time() and it seems like it actually takes more time?

Comment: Parallel processing doesn’t always guarantee faster execution, especially for small datasets or when the overhead of parallelization outweighs the benefits. In your case, with a relatively small dataset (5 rows), the overhead of parallelization may indeed result in longer execution times.

Comment: Parallel processing is most beneficial for large datasets where the computational tasks are significant and can be effectively divided among multiple cores. For small datasets, the overhead of parallelization, including the setup and communication between processes, can sometimes outweigh the gains from parallel execution.

Comment: @youtube, please try this with your large data (as mentioned in question 3 million), It will work efficiently for sure

Comment: @youtube how's the performance? with %timeit?

Comment: for the large dataset- it's still running and its been ~16 hours (this is with 1 core). I'm also running w/ multiple cores- started around 4 hours ago- still not done.